# Unity First Person Controller Error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am having this error with the first person controller.

transform.localRotation assign attempt for 'FirstPersonCharacter' is not valid. Input rotation is { NaN, NaN, NaN, 1.000000 }.

Please help.

Comment: Look at the places where `localRotation` is being set, make sure the values are legal.

Comment: Provide us some of your code.